# Use ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore directly in a model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to use  ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore dirctly in a model class:

```
@backend_cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::FileCache.new Rails.root.join("tmp", "cache")
```

The program reports a NameError

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Cache::FileCache
Did you mean?  FileTest
```

I added

```
require "active_support"
require "active_support/core_ext"
```

It still shows the error. I know that I can use Rails.Cache for the purpose, but the object I cached must be on the disk, which is different from other parts of the application.

The application is written in Rails 6.

Comment: I think you have a typo: `::FileStore.new` instead of `FileCache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this inside a rails 6 console and it works just fine.

```
@backend_cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore.new(Rails.root.join("tmp", "cache"))
@backend_cache.write('x', 1) # => true
@backend_cache.read('x') # => 1
```

It's just typo I mentioned in the comment. It's `::FileStore.new` instead of `::FileCache.new`